# Design: Links in comment undetectable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I put my browser at 100% zoom, and took a snapshot of a comment:

> [image]

Which words are clickable? It isn't clear enough.

Hovering over the link makes it blend in even further, if that is possible.

Note: If anything, it is clearer in this picture than the original site. The image is slightly fuzzy, making the link slightly bolder than the original?

Comment: Comment [with](https://www.google.com) link to test better.

Comment: @Sklivvz Wow. That's invisible. I will always prefer colored links. Every site on the SE network uses this type of link and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.